How to Convert Media Gallery Slider to a Vertical Slider in Hyva Theme Magento 2?
I'm working on a Magento 2 Hyva Theme project and need to convert the default Media Gallery slider into a vertical slider. Currently, the slider displays images horizontally, but I want it to scroll vertically instead. Can someone provide guidance or point me in the right direction on how to achieve this customization within Hyva Theme Magento 2?

I am using the code shared by adminsab. Slider vertically added but the arrow is not working the height keeps increasing.Please see the attachment

You can use hyva UI component "Gallery" to archive vertical thumbnail slider

You need to adjust the CSS and possibly the HTML structure to make the thumbnails scroll vertically instead of horizontally. Here's what you can do:
<div id="thumbs"
 class="flex items-center flex-col" <!-- Updated -->
 :class="{ 'fixed justify-center bottom-0 left-0 right-0 mx-6': fullscreen }"
 style="min-height: 100px;"
 x-show="images.length > 1"
 x-cloak



<button
    type="button"
    aria-label="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Previous')) ?>"
    tabindex="-1"
    class="mr-4 text-black rounded-full outline-none focus:outline-none flex-none"
    :class="{ 'opacity-25 pointer-events-none' : activeSlide === 0, 'hidden' : !isSlider }"
    aria-hidden="true"
    @click="scrollPrevious"
><?= $heroicons->chevronUpHtml() ?></button> <!-- Updated -->
<div class="js_thumbs_slides thumbs-wrapper relative flex flex-col w-full overflow-auto js_slides snap md:px-1 xl:px-2" <!-- Updated -->
     x-ref="jsThumbSlides"
     @scroll.debounce="calcPageSize(); calcActive()"
>
    <template x-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index">
        <div class="js_thumbs_slide flex-shrink-0 mb-2 mr-2 lg:mr-4 last:mr-0">
            <button
                type="button"
                @click.prevent="setActive(index);"
                class="block border border-gray-300 hover:border-primary focus:border-primary"
                :class="{'border-primary': active === index}"
            >
                <span class="sr-only">
                    <?= $escaper->escapeHtml('View larger image') ?>
                </span>
                <img
                    :src="image.thumb"
                    :alt="hyva.str('%1 thumbnail', image.caption) || '<?= $escaper->escapeJs(__("%1 thumbnail", $productName)) ?>'"
                    :title="hyva.str('%1 thumbnail', image.caption) || '<?= $escaper->escapeJs(__("%1 thumbnail", $productName)) ?>'"
                    width="<?= /* @noEscape */ $smallWidth ?>"
                    height="<?= /* @noEscape */ $smallHeight ?>"
                />
            </button>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
<button
    type="button"
    x-show="images.length > 1"
    x-cloak
    aria-label="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Next')) ?>"
    tabindex="-1"
    class="ml-4 text-black rounded-full outline-none focus:outline-none flex-none"
    :class="{ 'opacity-25 pointer-events-none' : activeSlide >= itemCount-pageSize, 'hidden' : !isSlider }"
    aria-hidden="true"
    @click="scrollNext"
><?= $heroicons->chevronDownHtml() ?></button> <!-- Updated -->

